# react-native socket.io endless requests from node server

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am trying a very simple expo App just to see how to use the socket.io and connect it to the server and this is my App.js-

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {io} from "socket.io-client";
export const  socket = io('http://0f03e059b74d.ngrok.io', {
  transports: ["websocket"]
})

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

but for some reason, the app is doing an endless of requests to connect from the server:
[image]
and I don't know how to stop this and to have only one connection?
this is the server.js-

```
const express = require('express');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const colors = require('colors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/error');
const connectDB = require('./config/db.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let compression = require('compression');
let helmet = require('helmet');

//load env vars
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' });

// connect to data base
connectDB(); 

// Routs files
const auth = require('./routes/auth');

const app = express();

//body parser to read from req.body
app.use(express.json());

//Compress all routes
app.use(compression());

//protect against  vulnerabilities
app.use(helmet());

// prod logging middleware
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`) {
  app.use(morgan(`dev`));
}

//mount ruters
app.use('/api/v1/auth', auth);
app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
);

let io = socket(server);
app.set('socketio', io);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('try to connect');
  console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

// handle unhandled promise rejections
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, Promise) => {
  console.log(`Errore:${err.massage}`.red);
  //close server & exit process
  server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

I would appreciate any help I can get.
server - https://github.com/MakGyv3r/socket_api.git
app-https://github.com/MakGyv3r/socket_app.git

Comment: Are you sure you've pasted the exact code? As it seems it's trying to connect to different domain than `example.com`, and that shouldn't happen.

Comment: example.com is just an example of a URL, I am using ngrok URL to connect to the server. i put the ngrok url in the code.

Comment: I think it's best if you publish your sample in some sandbox (like https://codesandbox.io/ ) otherwise I don't think we can help..

Comment: i attched the git linkes 
server - https://github.com/MakGyv3r/socket_api.git 
app- https://github.com/MakGyv3r/socket_app.git

Comment: I tried to add the app to the send box but it doesn't recognize react-native dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem was solved, the dependence for socket.io wasn't updated for 4.1.2.